# Detail List Button - need to define record type

Tags: record-type

I have two custom objects:

```
**Cov__c** 
Risk__c: Picklist (Terr, Prop)

**Add__c**
Cov__c (Master Detail Lookup)
```

I have created a detail button for **Add__c**, which I want to make visible on the related list on the **Cov__c** detail page.

When the picklistfield **Risk__c** is set to **Terr**, I want to open a specific page layout/record type called **Terr_RT**.

This is what I have written on the detail button:

```
{!IF( ISPICKVAL(Cov__c.Risk__c,'Terr'), '/a0Z/e?ent=01I180000004KaV&RecordType=012180000008Tw5, '/a0Z/e?ent=01I180000004KaV&RecordType=012180000008Tw0')}
```

How can I avoid hardcoding the record type? ...and is there a better way of doing this?

Tia.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate option would be to create a Publisher Action for that Record Type to be displayed on Cov__c's detail page. I'm assuming the button displays all the time just like a Publisher Action button does unless you have custom code to only show it under certain circumstances.